# Is 'RFI' a term in active usage, or is it all 'EMI' now?

Tags: capacitor, emc, bypass-capacitor

I'm studying capacitors in some detail just now, and one of their typical uses, of course, is to bypass high frequency interference at sensitive circuit inputs.

I want to get my terms straight, and it seems like this interference is widely called *electromagnetic interference* (EMI) and the term *radio frequency interference* (RFI) is not used or not often distinguished at least.

I understand that, technically, a distinction can be drawn between the two with RFI perhaps being a subset of EMI. But my question is about common parlance and terminology that is effective in practice.

When describing the purpose of a capacitor placed to bypass typical unwanted interference, am I right to use the term EMI by itself; as in "C1 is a 0.33uF metallized polyester cap for EMI bypass"? Or is it useful to maintain a distinction between EMI and RFI for bypass purposes?

Comment: I see EMI more often than RFI. You may also see EMC (electro magnetic compliance), which includes not only emissions but immunity to emissions and ESD from outside, and there is a further distinction sometimes made between radiated and conducted immunity or emissions.

Comment: RFI is a subset and covers only radio waves i.e. 9kHz and above.